# Redirect selected option on submit laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I redirect my selected option when I click submit?
I am trying to make a modal Sign Up that is located in the header for different users. When the user choose one, they will then be redirected to specific sign up page.

This is from my header.blade.php

```
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Choose Roles/Plan</h4>       
         <div class="input-field col s12">
           <select id="select-action" name = "action">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="basicsignup">Basic</option>
            <option value="advancedsignup">Advanced</option>
            <option value="teamsignup">Team</option>
           </select>
         </div>
     </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/basicsignup', function(){
    return view('actions.basicsignup');
})->name('basicsignup');

Route::get('/advancedsignup', function(){
    return view('actions.advancedsignup');
})->name('advancedsignup');

Route::get('/teamsignup', function(){
    return view('actions.teamsignup');
})->name('teamsignup');
```

Edit: Original examples were animals, flowers, cars.. edited it for clarity at least.

Comment: add some more details for your question.... Is drop is independent OR part of any HTML FOrm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use JavaScript `onsubmit` function to call a JS function than get your selected value and then you can submit a form with your customised url.

**Example**

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
    <select id="select-action" name="action">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
       <option value ="animals">Animals</option>
       <option value ="flowers">Flowers</option>
       <option value ="cars">Cars</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitForm() {
        var selectedOption = $('#select-action').val();
        var url = "";
        if(selectedOption == 'animals') {
            url = '{{ route('your/route')}}';
        } else if (selectedOption == 'flowers') {
            url = '{{ route('your/route')}}';
        }
        .
        .
        .

        $('#myForm').attr('action', url);
        $('form#myForm').submit();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```